Does 1 Samuel 18:1 completely change the theology of Christianity?

After David had finished talking with Saul, Jonathan became one in
spirit with David, and he loved him as himself.

Here, there is a definition of oneness. Oneness is loving someone as yourself. Therefore, when Jesus says that he and the Father are one (John 10:30), he means that he loves the Father as himself.
Love God and your neighbor as yourself.
Does the verse change the understanding of “oneness” away from being a statement of divinity within the Holy Trinity doctrine? Does it open up the interpretation that being “one in Spirit with God” means to love God as you love yourself, and therefore there can be any number of persons as part of Holy Unity? There would no longer be a Holy Trinity because Jesus himself was not claiming to be God but only that he had a Spirit from God and therefore was one in Spirit with God the Father through love.

I think theology is based on far more than your two texts!!  1 Sam 18:1 does NOT say that David and Jonathon were "one" but "one in spirit".  By contrast, Jesus never said that He was "one in spirit with the Father".  Please do not misquote Scripture.  Lastly, David's love for Jonathon appears to be carrying out the instruction in Lev 19:18 to "love your neighbor as yourself".  Thus, your assertion that 1 Sam 18:1 as a "definition" of oneness" is fallaciousness.

According my viewpoint, you would explain in what manner this Bible passage does change - "completely" - the teology of Christianity.

I don’t understand any other conclusion other than that “one” and “one in spirit” are synonymous expressions.

The Spirit comes from the Father, yes? That’s what Jesus said. To have the Spirit means to be one in Spirit. To do this means to love the Father. The Spirit is an expression of love. To love the Father, everyone, even enemies as you love yourself. That is being one in Spirit with God. So Jesus was not literally saying that he was God, but that he loved God as he loved himself and he taught that everyone should love in the same way as that so that the world becomes one in Spirit with God? Jesus came from the Father means he had the spirit  of the Father. Jesus was symbolically a spirt of love.

The NT is a separation and joining of two ideas. One in Spirit and One in Flesh. One in Flesh and of the flesh are synonymous. It refers to marriage and sex. A man and woman then create a baby and become one in flesh. The family becomes as though one in Spirit. God’s family is one in Spirit. Hence you get the idea of the Holy Trinity and the Church married to Christ, sons of God as one in Spirit with the Father through Christ and the Church. Christ’s words are the leader of the Church and the leader is called Lord. The Church spoke of Jesus as being the Lord, the leader.

The Church quite literally does not have a King (Son of God) existing here on Earth, nor a Kingdom. So eventually the idea must be that the King and Kingdom is not of this world and must therefore be God. This happened because the prophecy of Jesus returning after the crucifixion to become the King of the Kingdom did not occur as expected

And that’s why the prophecy was not extremely successful at converting Jewish people; because they already had a prophecy about God being the King and Saviour going on for almost a thousand years then.

@ReturnOfRoamer "..are synonymous expressions", same as "I've eaten a fruit", and "I've eaten an apple". You are trying to state that such expressions is a reasonable and logical way to make interchangeability of fruits and apples possible by equality in every place. Apples are fruits from some perspective, that is true, but the opposite is nonsense. From the other hand it is true that the fruits can be antonymous to apples, if the perspective is chosen specifically to see the difference. You can't find a banana in an apple and get one from another, but a fruit occasionally can be a banana.

This question could be improved: 1) It should explicitly say how it would "completely change things; 2) "Jesus says" should be an explicit quotation; 3) "Therefore" should begin a new paragraph; 4) The last sentence doesn't have an obvious purpose.

Ok, will do that

Jesus was possessed by a spirit called God, the Holy Spirit. This happened when he was baptised by John. The Holy Spirit, God, then came over him and merged with his spirit. They became one. This can hardly be said to have happened between David and Jonathan, can it? Well, if Jonathan was God in disguise, then it is similar. Maybe he was.

But anyone can become possessed by the Spirit of God, or Holy Spirit so that means anybody can become as much a part of God than Jesus. It’s merely that Jesus was chosen to become the King of Judea (Son of God) which didn’t literally happen because the Sanhedrin and Roman courts had him executed because he claimed to be King of the Jews, which he literally wasn’t.

If Jesus had not been executed the apostles, disciples, and follower would’ve continued on as though Jesus was an earthly King. Because he was executed there’s not much choice than to say the King is now in heaven sitting at the right hand of God.

I think it says somewhere that Jesus is the firstborn among many brothers. Jesus also said : “A time will come when you will not ask me for anything, because the Father himself loves you”

This is a place for honest questions, not for preaching disguised as questions and then followed by attempts to reinforce the message in comments.

To be “one” one in Spirit means to love as you love yourself. To love means to obey the law and exercise justice according to how the law is enforced upon yourself. To then not love means to be unfair and racist.

lots of divinity - John 17:22 And the glory which You gave Me I have given them, that they may be one just as We are one:

Even if the claim is correct, the verse doesn't "completely change the theology of Christianity".
At most it provides a minor support for unitarianism (one supreme being) and binitarianism (two supreme beings, one choosing to be subordinate to the other), and not for the doctrine of the Trinity mystery (three supreme beings that also exist as a single being in a way that can't be understood by the mind of man except by analogy).
These theologies already exist; they aren't even slightly changed by this scripture.

As for the claim itself, it is based on the NIV translation "Jonathan became one in spirit with David".
The other translations don't have "one in spirit". E.g.:

KJV: "the soul of Jonathan was knit with the soul of David".
NLT: "there was an immediate bond between them".
CSB: "Jonathan was bound to David in close friendship".
NASB: "Jonathan committed himself to David".
NET: "Jonathan and David became bound together in close friendship".

Looking at these translations (and others) it's easy to see the underlying commonality and the intended meaning.
In the original Hebrew, the niphal verb קָשַׁר (qāšar) means
"to be bound, be bound up".
One shouldn't rely upon a single translation of the Bible.
The NIV's use of the expression "one in spirit", is simply their way of conveying the original meaning into English.
It is not a literal translation, and cannot be used out of context for doctrinal proof.

Can 1 Samuel 18 at least be considered a biblical definition of one, oneness, one in spirit? Or is it a completely wrong translation because the Hebrew speaks of them conspiring together in person, not that they are one in spirit? The Hebrew word “nephash” does not mean spirit. https://biblehub.com/text/1_samuel/18-1.htm

@ReturnOfRoamer, "Can 1 Samuel 18 at least be considered a biblical definition of one, oneness, one in spirit?". If you are asking whether "he loved him as himself" and "one in spirit" have very similar meanings, then yes. If you are asking about the word "spirit", or the word "one", then no. (See my addition to the answer.)

The theological doctrine is an extremely exaggerated misinterpretation of the dramatic poetic Hebrew language that simply means like brotherhood. Not brothers and sisters, nor sons and fathers in the biological sense. That’s how I have seen it happen in real life. There’s nothing supernatural occurring.

Short answer:  The doctrine of the Trinity is not based solely on this single verse so it wouldn't sufficiently change it. Now, if it were definitively proven that “one” in this context does not imply a unity of essence or substance, it could challenge the use of this verse in support of the Trinity.
1) Looking at John 10
John 10:30 says:

30 I and My Father are one.”

The first thing to note is:

Part of the meaning of this statement is lost in translation from
Greek to English. Jesus uses the "neuter" form of the Greek word for
"one" here, implying that they are "unity." Rather than saying that
Jesus and God are the same person, Jesus is claiming that He and God
are unified as one, a partial explanation of the Trinity.  [3] 

The verses right before this are also important. John 10:28-29 says:

28 And I give them eternal life, and they shall never perish; neither
shall anyone snatch them out of My hand. 29 My Father, who has given
them to Me, is greater than all; and no one is able to snatch them out
of My Father’s hand.

Ellicott's Commentary lists several arguments we can take as reasons for not defining oneness in this verse as being "loving someone as yourself". I will summarize the points:

Identity: The last clause of John 10:29 is identical with the last clause of John 10:28 if we identify “Father’s” with “My.” This is something that Jesus does formally.
Jesus' assertion of divine power: John 10:28-29 speak of a power greater than all, and these words are an assertion that in the infinity of All-mighty Power, the Son is one with the Father.
Unity of essence, not person: The Greek word for “one” is neuter, indicating that the unity is of essence, not of person. This means that “The Son is of one substance with the Father.”
Distinctness and co-ordination: The use of the plural “are” asserts distinctness, countering Sabellianism, and the “one” asserts co-ordination, countering Arianism.
More than unity of will: Despite attempts to interpret these words as implying only a unity of will between the Father and the Son, they assert both oneness of power and oneness of nature.
Divinity of Jesus: The best answer to all attempts to attach any    meaning lower than that of the divinity of our Lord to these His words is found here, as in the parallel instance in John 8:58-59, in the conduct of the Jews themselves.


John 8:58-59 Jesus said to them, “Most assuredly, I say to you, before
Abraham was, I AM.” Then they took up stones to throw at Him; but
Jesus hid Himself and went out of the temple, going through the midst
of them, and so passed by.


Reaction of the Jews: The Jews sought to punish Jesus by stoning, because they believed that Jesus, being a man, was making himself God
(John 10:31-33).


31 Then the Jews took up stones again to stone Him. 32 Jesus answered
them, “Many good works I have shown you from My Father. For which of
those works do you stone Me?”
33 The Jews answered Him, saying, “For a good work we do not stone
You, but for blasphemy, and because You, being a Man, make Yourself
God.”

On a side note. I think the fact that no church fathers interpret "one" with this definition is evidence for it not being used in such a manner as defined.
2) Looking at 1 Samuel 18:1

Now when he had finished speaking to Saul, the soul of Jonathan was
knit to the soul of David, and Jonathan loved him as his own soul.

The word for "was knit" is:

qashar: to bind, league together, conspire
Original Word: קָשַׁר

It should be noted that the original languages of these two books are different. The Old Testament was written in Hebrew, while the New Testament was written in Greek.
This word qashar is the same word found in Genesis 44:30.

30 “Now therefore, when I come to your servant my father, and the lad
is not with us, since his life is bound up in the lad’s life, 31 it
will happen, when he sees that the lad is not with us, that he will
die. So your servants will bring down the gray hair of your servant
our father with sorrow to the grave.


The bond of friendship which Jonathan formed with David was so
evidently the main point, that in 1 Samuel 18:1 the writer commences
with the love of Jonathan to David...  [10] 

Clincher: What is something that is important in making this comparison of oneness being defined as: "Oneness is loving someone as yourself" in both 1 Samuel 18 and John 10?
The presence of the word love. 1 Samuel 18 makes it clear that we are indeed talking about love.

Jonathan loved him as his own soul.

On the other hand, the relevant verses of John 10 say nothing about love which would indicate that Jesus is talking about it.
I conclude then that there is not sufficient evidence to read John 10 with the definition proposed for oneness as "loving someone as yourself".




References:




3
What does John 10:30 mean? BibleRef.com. (n.d.). BibleRef.com. https://www.bibleref.com/John/10/John-10-30.html


5
John 10 Ellicott’s commentary for English readers. (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/john/10.htm


10
1 Samuel 18 Keil and Delitzsch OT Commentary. (n.d.). https://biblehub.com/commentaries/kad/1_samuel/18.htm




KJV JOHN 12:49: For I have not spoken of myself; but the Father which sent me, he gave me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak. (Jesus speaks on behalf of the Father like a power of attorney in a court of law who speaks speaks on behalf of his client who is not present in the courtroom. A prophet.)

@ReturnOfRoamer I agree that Jesus spoke on behalf of the Father. I think that the evidence still stands as a low probability for using the given definition for "one".

John 10:30 should be translated as “I and the one Father exist.” ?

Matthew 5:41 is an example where the adjective “one” is written after the word it describes (Greek translation) so the same could be applied to John 10:30. https://biblehub.com/text/matthew/5-41.htm

arguably the Apostles were also God / trihity John 17:22 And the glory which You gave Me I have given them, that they may be one just as We are one:

@anothertheory. Just four verses after the quoted John 10:30, is John 10:34, "Jesus answered them, Is it not written in your law, I said, Ye are gods?".

@RayButterworth - You need to read on to John 10:36 which clarifies.  That’s a quote from Psalms 82 – God describes the prophets as ‘gods’ therefore he calling himself ‘son of God’ is no claim to divinity.  Many sons of God – Ex 7:1 And the LORD said unto Moses, See, I have made thee a god to Pharaoh: and Aaron thy brother shall be thy prophet. Luke 3:38 "...Adam which was the Son of God."  Exodus 4:22 "Israel is my son even my first born." Genesis 6:2 &4 "That the sons of God saw the daughters of men...and when the sons of God came in unto the daughters of men..."so on

No, I’m not saying the apostles or Jesus was God. They are often treated within theology as being like God because their words are given the highest authority. So God is more like an adjective rather a noun. I agree with that.

I’m trying to explain that the Spirit of God allows anyone with it to act of behalf of God. Not that they are actually God, but given authority from God through the Spirit. Prophets like Jesus and the apostles and OT prophets and Moses.

The Sanhedrin and King of Israel/Judea act on behalf of God. They were the earthly representatives of God. Not really God itself.

When someone has the Spirit of God they become “one” with God, but not actually God in the sense they are same substance as God mentioned in the later Holy Trinity linguistics

Jonathon and David become “one” is that sense because they chose to work together to prevent King Saul from executing David.

@ReturnOfRoamer - yes I agree with you HS is not a person but the spirit of God - I am making the same point that all these passages that people rely on do not make Jesus God - otherwise we would literally have Gods and sons of God in the dozens.

The NT doesn’t write that Jesus was God. It writes that Jesus was the Lord of the apostles or anyone. The word Lord is highly misunderstood because of the LXX, because the Jews didn’t want to accept or acknowledge slavery to anybody from another race so they applied the slave and master word of Lord to their God. People read it nowadays and think Lord means God, but it doesn’t. It’s all because of slavery and racism that the concept of sin exists.
